# For how long Google calendar channel (Events: watch) lives?

Tags: google-calendar-api, webhooks

Hey is there anyone who can answer this question,

does the google calendar api channel lifetime depends on which one:

1) it is valid as long as the access token expires.

2) it is valid depending on the ttl(in seconds) you specify during its creation.

What would happen if I set the ttl really big and the access token expires? Will the channel be active?

**What I am building:**

I am using webhook method and the google server notifies my when something changes.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by `channel`? Are you talking about [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push). 
Also if you problem is with OAuth2 authorization I would recommend to take a look at [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: I don't have any technical problem at this moment. I am talking about this one https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I figured out that the Google Channel is going to notify you until the **ttl**(time to live) passes by.

Also even if user revoke the permission he gave you, the channel is still active and returns changes to events like nothing has happened.

TL;DR

Only ttl matters for the lifetime of the channel